# Xamarin to Generate Tone for iOS

Tags: c#, ios, audio, xamarin, avfoundation

I am trying to use Xamarin to create a synthesizer for iOS.  Does anyone know how I can create a basic tone using Xamarin targeting the iOS platform?  I prefer not to use a sample but to use one of the native APIs to generate the tone. Are there any other helpful tip you can give me to create my app?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rgcottrell/5b876d9c5eea4c9e411c Don't look for specific code for Xamarin, in this case just search for native solutions and the code is portable 1:1 as Xamarin implements all the native classes.

Comment: Thanks Gusman.  C# is one of the languages I use and I have very little knowledge of Objective-C or Swift.  If I take the native code and put it into my solution I don't think it would benefit me much because I don't understand it.  But if I did understand it I would build a native iOS app, so it's kind of a catch 22.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're missing all, it doesn't matters if it's objc or swift, the classes, functions and properties are the same on Xamarin, per example, *private let engine: AVAudioEngine = AVAudioEngine()* would be *private AVAudioEngine engine = new AVAudioEngine();*, as you see it's only a syntactic change, the essence of the code is exactly the same

Comment: I agree with @Gusman, while you might not have to `program` with ObjC/Swift/Java to use Xamarin, you DO need to be able to translate code fragments from those languages as C# is never going to be a `native` language on those platforms with C# code samples provided by Google/Apple. Learning the `native` platform and their SDKs in-depth will only make you a stronger mobile programmer (no matter which language you code them in)

Comment: So if am going to learn the native SDKs 'in-depth', which means that I would have to learn ObjC and/or Swift at least at an intermediate level.  Why would I not just code my apps in ObjC or Swift instead of C# at that point?

Comment: You have to look at the code sharing attributes of using Xamarin, C#/F# and the eco-system of development tools for Visual Studio. If you do not plan on code reuse across iOS, Android and Windows projects, then correct, using `native` toolsets and languages *might* be a more direct path to solve your development goals. Xamarin is a **great** toolset, I love it, but if you do not understand what a segue is, how storyboards work, disposing of Java objects, create view controllers, etc.. than you will limiting your own ability to code apps, being a cut/paste programmer only goes so far.

Comment: Thanks SushiHangover, that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Gusman, the code you posted from gitHub looks great.  I could not get it to build because it does not find FMSynthesizer as a type (but it is obviously a class right below where it is called).  Do I need to do something special in Xcode or Xamarin to get it to build?

Comment: I am considering the native route now, but let's say my synthesizer well be built for iOS, Android, and Windows Phone.  Since a synthesizer would be mostly graphical and I am assuming would have to call each environments native APIs for sound, there would not be a lot of opportunity for code reuse through Xamarin would it?  Thanks.